# Will wget replace downloaded key if a && a.html both existed

Tags: wget

Setup simple static http-server with 3 files. Suppose host is http://127.0.0.1:8082.

- a && a.html, with the same content that contains a link to `b`

```
<body>
    <a href="b"></a>
</body>
```

- b, which contains 2 links to the same name url but different suffixes.

```
<body>
    <a href="a"></a>
    <a href="a.html"></a>
</body>
```

I try with `wget -E -m -p -k http://127.0.0.1:8082/a` and expect both links in `b` will be converted to relative paths. But in fact, the result is,

```
<body>
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8082/a"></a>
    <a href="a.html"></a>
</body>
```

I guess that wget treats a && a.html as the same file(as -E). When converting links in b, the existed a was mistaken as not downloaded because a.html overwrote the downloaded key.

---

```
[zhong@localhost wget]$ wget -E -m -p -k http://127.0.0.1:8082/a
- 2019-02-09 20:58:42 -- http://127.0.0.1:8082/a
Connecting 127.0.0.1:8082... Connected.
HTTP request has been issued, waiting for response... 200 OK
Length: 35 [text/html]
Save to "127.0.0.1:8082/a.html"

127.0.0.1:8082/a.html 100%[=========================>] 35 - - KB/s takes 0s

2019-02-09 20:58:42 (4.17 MB/s) - Preserved "127.0.0.1:8082/a.html" [35/35])

Robots.txt is being loaded; please ignore the error message.
- 2019-02-09 20:58:42 -- http://127.0.0.1:8082/robots.txt
Reuse existing connections to 127.0.0.1:8082.
An HTTP request has been issued and is awaiting a response... 404 Not Found

2019-02-09 20:58:42 Error 404: Not Found.
Conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-8 is not supported
- 2019-02-09 20:58:42 -- http://127.0.0.1:8082/b
Reuse existing connections to 127.0.0.1:8082.
HTTP request has been issued, waiting for response... 200 OK
Length: 61 [text/html]
Save to "127.0.0.1:8082/b.html"

127.0.0.1:8082/b.html 100%[=========================>] 61 - - KB/s takes 0s

2019-02-09 20:58:42 (7.27 MB/s) - Preserved "127.0.0.1:8082/b.html" [61/61])
Conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-8 is not supported

- 2019-02-09 20:58:42 -- http://127.0.0.1:8082/a.html
Reuse existing connections to 127.0.0.1:8082.
HTTP request has been issued, waiting for response... 200 OK
Length: 35 [text/html]
Save to "127.0.0.1:8082/a.html"

127.0.0.1:8082/a.html 100%[=========================>] 35 - - KB/s takes 0s

2019-02-09 20:58:42 (2.78 MB/s) - Preserved "127.0.0.1:8082/a.html" [35/35])

Download completed -- 2019-02-09 20:58:42--
Total time: 0.009s
Downloaded: 3 files, 131 in 0s (4.46 MB/s)
Links in 127.0.0.1:8082/a.html are being converted... 1-0
Links in 127.0.0.1:8082/b.html are being converted... 1-1
Links in two files have been converted in 0.001 seconds
```

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. I get, `will convert url http://localhost:8000/a to local localhost:8000/a` and `will convert url http://localhost:8000/a.html to local localhost:8000/a.html`.   Please share the _full_ contents of all three files and the full output of wget with `-d` option

Comment: @darnir I use GNU Wget 1.20.1 built on darwin18.2.0. Sorry without -d support. The whole contents of 3 files are shown above.

Comment: Atleast switch the language to English.

Comment: @darnir Didn't find a way to set i18n in wget. But translated the output by a website and it looks good.